# An Exception in my code when i using Spring.NET as IOCness

Tags: c#, asp.net, ioc-container, spring.net

first ,please look my exception infos in below:

```
exception time：2013-10-15 09:08:30,765 [1] 
exception level：ERROR 
exception class：logerror [(null)] 
SpringFactory.GetObject(adminFacade) 
 System.InvalidOperationException: root context is currently in creation. You must not call ContextRegistry.GetContext() from e.g. constructors of your singleton objects
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.InitializeContextIfNeeded()
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
   at Domain.common.SpringFactory.GetObject(String objectId) in F:\gitlab\huatongmis.git\HuaTongBusinessWeb\Domain\common\SpringFactory.cs:line 38
```

there are some exception infos like that in my project log files,actually it does not make my project break down. but I treat it as a terrible problem.it puzzled me for a long time.

please see the exception point in my code file.

```
public class SpringFactory
        {
            private static IApplicationContext _applicationContext;

            private SpringFactory(){}


            public static Object GetObject(string objectId)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_applicationContext == null)
                    {
                        _applicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.WriteLog(string.Format("SpringFactory.GetObject({0})",objectId), ex);
                }
                return _applicationContext.GetObject(objectId);
            }
        }
```

I use the IOc just like this

```
public class Order : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public HTSoapHeader htSoapHeader;
        private OrderFacade orderFacade { get; set; }
        private TicketFacade ticketFacade { get; set; }
        private CarrentalFacade carrentalFacade { get; set; }
        private AdminFacade adminFacade { get; set; }
        public Order()
        {
            orderFacade = (OrderFacade)SpringFactory.GetObject("orderFacade");
            ticketFacade = (TicketFacade)SpringFactory.GetObject("ticketFacade");
            carrentalFacade = (CarrentalFacade)SpringFactory.GetObject("carrentalFacade");
            adminFacade = (AdminFacade)SpringFactory.GetObject("adminFacade");
        }
}
```

how it happened and how to solve the problem.
looking forward to having your any answer, thanks

today i remember that i user spring.net injection in my global.asax.the code is :

```
   public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            private AdminFacade adminFacade;

            public Global()
            {
                // 
                //initial log
                var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase +
                               WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4net"];
                var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi);
                adminFacade = (AdminFacade)SpringFactory.GetObject("adminFacade");
            }

            void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //print profile sql
                HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();

                //load all rights
                AllSystemRights.Rights = adminFacade.GetRightSer().LoadAllAllSystemRights();

            }
          .........other events
}
```

here is the exception point in spring.core.dll ,en the source code

```
public static IApplicationContext GetContext()
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        InitializeContextIfNeeded();
        if (rootContextName == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationContextException("No context registered. Use the 'RegisterContext' method or the 'spring/context' section from your configuration file.");
        }
        return GetContext(rootContextName);
    }
}
```

the code in method ‘InitializeContextIfNeeded’ :

```
private static void InitializeContextIfNeeded()
{
    if (rootContextName == null)
    {
        if (rootContextCurrentlyInCreation)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("root context is currently in creation. You must not call ContextRegistry.GetContext() from e.g. constructors of your singleton objects");
        }
        rootContextCurrentlyInCreation = true;
        try
        {
            ConfigurationUtils.GetSection("spring/context");
        }
        finally
        {
            rootContextCurrentlyInCreation = false;
        }
    }
}
```

any you help is desired

Comment: You are more or less misusing the IOC container as service locator. Anyway the issue should not occur, as a global lock is used to make the initialization thread safe. Can you please post the used Spring.Net version and in what kind of environment you are working?(IIS8, ASMX-Webservices?) Are you able to produce a small sample?

Comment: thanks for you answer,Actually that exception is not in a small sample.it's occured in my commercial project .my Project is based on PlinqO NhiberNate+Spring.NET.the version of spring.net is 1.3.2.40943. And the working inveronment is IIS8+WebService,as you see the code above,the service is injected by Spring.net through facade.expecially the exception is a random exception,that means the exception will not occur in every runtime.it is confused me so long time..thanks so much

Comment: I append some code above,I am doubt the exception is occur at global intialization,but why

Comment: You can only call ApplicationContext.GetObject(objectId) when the container is created. But the Order class calls GetObject in his constructor en because it is a singleton it wil be construct in the initialization of the container. To fix this you can inject the properties of the Order class by "Constructor-based dependency injection" or "Setter-based dependency injection".

Comment: thanks for your answer,maybe i need some more infos,this afternoo ,I open the spring.core.dll by using .net reflector.exe,and I find the exception point.but i dont know how can i avoid that exception.ok,having a look for the code in spring.core.dll where my exception occured. I append the code  above

Comment: thank u for you answer,I found the root cause which result in that exception.It's my IIS.my project is deploied on iis7.0 with integrerad pipeline mode.But during initialization of the spring IOC container,there is a action that rewriting Httpcontext.Unfortunately, In the pipe events of application such as the constructor of Global,and the Application_Start event.the httpcontext is not initialized under The IIS7.0 integrerad pipeline mode. that is the root cause which giving the exception.